# Reference request for book on design patterns with foreword by Christopher Alexander

Tags: reference-request, design-patterns

I do recall having found a book on software design patterns with a foreword by Christopher Alexander. Now, as is well known Alexander is credited as the creator of the concept of design patterns and design languages. In this particular text, he also described how he first came to know his work was being used in computer science. Does someone know what is that book, and what edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be *Patterns of Software* by Richard P. Gabriel (Oxford University Press, 1996)? Here's an excerpt from the foreword by Christopher Alexander:

> A year or two ago, I was astonished to get several letters from different people in
> the computer science field, telling me that my name was a household word in the
> software engineering community: specifically in the field of object-oriented technology. I had never even heard of object-oriented programming, and I had absolutely no idea that computer scientists knew my work, or found it useful or
> interesting; all this was a revelation to me. It was a pleasant revelation, but one
> that I did not really grasp at first; nor did I think much about it. I assumed the
> people who wrote to me were exaggerating anyway, out of politeness.
>
> Then, one of these people, Marc Sewell from IBM in Atlanta, came to see me
> and told me much the same, to my face, in a discussion over coffee. Naturally, I
> assumed he too was exaggerating. When I expressed my surprise and doubts
> about the depth of this “alexandrian patterns movement,” he told me that in any
> given issue of The Journal of Object-Oriented Programming, there was almost certain to be some mention of my name. To prove it the next day he came with the
> current issue of The Journal of Object-Oriented Programming. There was in it,
> an article by Richard Gabriel, the essay that appears in this book as the chapter
> entitled “The Bead Game, Rugs, and Beauty."

Comment: Yes! Thank you!